# dividing each sample by its maximum feature value separately, or dividing all samples by the maximum value across the entire dataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, tf-idf, data-processing

I am trying to reproduce a paper that uses the tf-idf method. During the data preprocessing, there is a step that involves feature scaling. In the original paper, it says, "We restrict the words to the most common 10,000 words in the train set; then, we scale each feature to be within [-1, 1], by dividing by the maximum absolute value of the feature across the train set." So, when it mentions dividing by the maximum absolute value, is it dividing each sample by its maximum feature value separately, or is it dividing all samples by the maximum value across the entire dataset?

not done yet......................

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**TF = (Number of repetitions of word in a document) / (# of words in a document)**

**IDF =Log[(Number of documents) / (Number of documents containing the word)]**

So TF-IDF value for a particular word is **TF value of that word * IDF Value of that word**.

Hence TF-IDF value ranges between **0 and inf**. TF-IDF cannot have **-ve** values

To bring it to range of **0 to 1**, **normalize** it by **dividing the TF-IDF value by the total number of words in the dataset**, in this case training dataset.

Please note that here document is synonym to a row in excel. So please understand that the value of TF-IDF for a particular word will be based on the **training dataset** alone.

So I am not sure what you are trying to do. It would be helpful if you can elaborate more to help you better.

Comment: Assuming there is a document filled with the word "a," totaling 1000 documents, and the other 999 documents do not contain the word "a," then the calculation of TF and IDF is as follows:
the word "a" appears 1000 times, and the total number of words is also 1000. So, TF("a") = 1000/1000 = 1.
In the entire document collection, there are 1000 documents, and only one document contains the word "a" . Therefore, IDF("a") = log(1000/1) = log(1000) ≈ 6.907.
TF-IDF("a") = TF("a") * IDF("a") = 1 * 6.907 ≈ 6.907.
In this example, the value of TF-IDF("a") is indeed greater than 1.

Comment: The original text is:
We utilise the classical technique term frequency – inverse document frequency (TF-IDF), which tokenises the sentences into words, then,a sentence is represented by a vector of the counts of the words it contains. The vector is then normalised by the term frequency across the entire Train set of the corresponding dataset. We restrict the words to the most common 10,000 words in the Train set, then we scale each feature to be within [−1, 1], by dividing by the maximum absolute value of the feature across the Train set